# Do I need to buy Mac OS X again?

Tags: macos, mac, snow-leopard, install

I am running 10.6.8 on my Mac Pro 1,1 and I want to reset it. I don't have the install disk anymore, so do I need to buy it again? Or can I copy the files from my system, and put them on a disk and boot from that? (I would prefer not to reinstall the OS, I just want to delete files, as it is getting pretty full, is there a way to only do that without completely reinstalling the OS?)

Comment: There is no real good method to "reset" an OS X installation except reinstalling or (with a somehow limited effect) creating a new user and moving all important data from the old to the new user

Answer (score 1):

I would say the best option might be to get software like Carbon Copy Cloner or use Disk Utility to clone the existing drive to another drive / external drive.

Then you could clean off the files on that OS and test that booting to it still works. Once you have something that works - you can re-clone or repeat the deletions on the main drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete files without having to make a copy of the system.  Are you looking for a way to make a backup that you can boot from if you accidentally delete the wrong files?  If so, there are several ways to do that.  I'd suggest looking into OS X Recovery https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314 which allows you to make clones of your primary drive (and do just about anything else that you want to the disk)